# Changing a UIView's frame causes content in new area to be untouchable

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, frame, bounds

So I want to expand a uiview in the case of a certain condition (a messaging application). I expand and contract the view using this code (and move around the picture appropriate buttons to be in the newer expanded region):

```
-(void)transformKeyBoardViewForPictureMessage:(int)heightToAdd
{
    //Resize whole view
    CGRect oldFrame = self.frame;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height + heightToAdd);
    //move up the preview imageview
    CGRect previewFrame = self.picPreview.frame;
    self.picPreview.frame = CGRectMake(previewFrame.origin.x, previewFrame.origin.y + heightToAdd, previewFrame.size.width, previewFrame.size.height);
    //move up the remove pic button
    self.removePicButton.frame = CGRectMake(removeFrame.origin.x, removeFrame.origin.y + heightToAdd, removeFrame.size.width, removeFrame.size.height);
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

This kind of works in that the removePicButton and picPreview get moved up and I can see them; however I can't touch the removePicButton nor any elements in the new area of the 'expanded frame' in addition the background color only gets reset inside the old frame of the view and not the new frame part (just has a clear background).

Comment: It looks to me like your moving your buttons up, while expanding your frame down. Just add: `oldFrame.origin.y + heightToAdd` and you should be fine.

Comment: So this is in a UIView subclass. When is this message called? Not in drawRect (I hope). Its seems a bit odd to have other view properties in a UIView subclass but I guess that should work. So where is this method called? Oh, and it better be on the main thread.

Comment: Seth.. this issue went pretty far down the rabbit hole; however the bug you pointed out also exists so if you answer I'll accept